# Stack smashing after read operation

Tags: c++, googletest

I have a following snippet of code:

```
static uint8_t decode_uint8(const uint8_t *& data)
{
    return *(data++);
}
```

to verify the functionality, I used the following test:

```
TEST(FOO, Decode8)
{
    const uint8_t stream[] = { 0xAA, 0xBB };

    const uint8_t* data = &stream[0];
    ASSERT_EQ(0xAA, decode_uint8(data));
    ASSERT_EQ(0xBB, decode_uint8(data));
}
```

after which I got:

```
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test suite.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from TDebugLog
[ RUN      ] TDebugLog.Decode8
*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I've used g++8.3.0 on Ubuntu 18.04.
Any ideas why is this happening?

Comment: Does your `ASSERT_EQ` macro somehow compute its parameters more than once?

Comment: Works outside of GoogleTest: https://wandbox.org/permlink/6ayE7nptWWFV0vo5

Comment: @MikeVine It's GTEST macro. And I've checked the address of data which got incremented by one after each ASSERT_EQ line so I'd say no

Comment: define a dummy one - say `#define MY_ASSERT_EQ(x, y) do{if((x)!=(y))printf("Not equal");}while(0)` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Another option I can guess is that a mismatched calling convention (either for decode_uint8 or for whatever functions gtests calls.

Comment: According to [GoogleTest documentation](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/release-1.8.0/googletest/docs/Primer.md): "Arguments are always evaluated exactly once. Therefore, it's OK for the arguments to have side effects." @Quest What did your debugger say about the crash?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen unfortunately not much: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHb7Z.png

Comment: @MikeVine I've tried your macro - same result tho. This is the only test running so I don't see why it should behave like that